# Double side lighting, backFace culling

Tags: meshlab

I have some instructions that I wrote for students using a previous version of MeshLab. The instructions are to do the following:

Render ► Lighting ► Double side lighting

Render ► Render Mode ► BackFace Culling

and

Filters ► Color Creation and Processing ► Color non Manifold Faces

None of these menu items seems to exist any more in version 2016.12. How do I get the equivalent effects now?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

They've made it pretty awkward to find the important rendering options in the latest version. It's hidden under the options for each mesh. Here's where to find the double lighting and culling:

[image]

And here is where the non-manifold vertices/edges and boundary edge highlighting are found:

[image]